# pySerial : Can't read data more than 8 characters

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyserial, serial-communication

I use pyserial to write and read between two Raspberry pi(s) via UART

Raspberry pi 1 : send data to Raspberry pi 2

```
    while 1:
        ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0')
        if not ser.isOpen():
            ser.open()
        msg=raw_input('RPi 1 send:')
        ser.write(msg)
        ser.close()
```

Raspberry pi 2 : receive data from Raspberry pi 1

```
    while 1:
        ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0' ,timeout=0)
        if not ser.isOpen():
            ser.open()
        data=ser.read(1024)
        if data.__len__()>0:
            print 'RPi 2 receive:',data
        ser.close()
```

I run both code.

and send data

```
    RPi 1 send : Hello
```

and receive data

```
    RPi 2 receive : Hello
```

But if RPi 1 send data more than 8 characters

for example

```
    RPi 1 send : Hello Raspberry pi NO.2
```

The result is

```
    RPi 2 receive: Hello Ra
    RPi 2 receive: spberry 
    RPi 2 receive: pi NO.2
```

This is my problem. Because I want it to receive like this

(RPi 2 receive: Hello Raspberry pi NO.2) #show only one line.

and if send (more 8 char) again, it show in a new line.

What code to join it in one line? or other way to do this? :)

Comment: read() only reads as much as is ready at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to do this

## sender.py

```
delim = "\x00"
ser.write(msg+delim)
```

## reciever.py

```
delim = "\x00"
recvd = "".join(iter(lambda:ser.read(1),delim))
print recvd
```

Comment: Now I edit code with your suggest and It show correctly.
but I am a new to python, and I don't know
Why you add "delim" ? and Why delim must be "\x00" ?
How does this line work "".join(iter(lambda:ser.read(1),delim))?
Would you describe this code for me? so Thanks a lot for answer :)

Comment: that line just says keep reading until we get our delimiter ... you can use any delimiter you want ... however \0 will (almost) never be in the actual message content so it is a good one to use

Answer (score 3):

When reading using `ser.read`, you're just reading what is already in the
buffer, or waiting for chars to arrive in the buffer. The size you specify
is a **maximum number of chars to receive**, but it can be much less as you
experienced.

You have 2 easy solutions:

1. use `ser.readline` and put a terminator in your strings (like \n)
2. if you know in advance how many characters to read, repeat reading
   until you've received them all

In both cases, specify a **timeout** (for example 1 second) when opening
the serial line, to get back control on your code if the remote end
doesn't send anything for whatever reason.

Hope it helps.